# Write only application related logs in log file in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have the below configuration in the application.properties file in my spring-boot application.

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger.%M - %msg%n

logging.file.name=my-app-api.log
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

in the "my-app-api.log" file I am getting server related log also like,

> 022-08-24 13:15:34 [restartedMain] DEBUG
> c.t.lab.LabSpringBootApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.7.3,
> Spring v5.3.22 2022-08-24 13:15:34 [restartedMain] INFO
> c.t.lab.LabSpringBootApplication - No active profile set, falling back
> to 1 default profile: "default" 2022-08-24 13:15:36 [restartedMain]
> INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring
> Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2022-08-24 13:15:36
> [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -
> Finished

But I only want application code related logs(do not want server logs) in that file.
Is is possible to configure in application.properties file of Spring-boot